# How can I have an unused type parameter in a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to update some older code I wrote that basically looks like:

```
trait Foo<T>{}

struct Bar<A, B: Foo<A>>{
  b: B
}
```

This used to work totally fine, but now I am getting a compile error:

```
src/test.rs:19:12: 19:13 error: parameter `A` is never used
src/test.rs:19 struct Bar<A, B: Foo<A>> {
                          ^
src/test.rs:19:12: 19:13 help: consider removing `A` or using a marker such as `core::marker::PhantomData`
```

So I can try to remove the type parameter and get something like this:

```
struct Bar<A>{
  b: Foo<A>
}
```

however this is not really what I want.  In my original code `B` resolves to a sized type, but now `Foo<A>` is unsized.

The other suggested solution is to try using this PhantomData the error mentions, resulting in:

```
struct Bar<A, B: Foo<A>> {
  b: B,
  marker: PhantomData<A>
}
```

but this seems really messy to me.  Reading the docs for `PhantomData` seem to indicate this is meant to be used with unsafe code, but I am not working with unsafe code anywhere here.  All I want is for `Bar` to contain an instance some type that implements `Foo`.

Is this really the only way to handle this situation now, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how your real `Foo` is, you might be able to work with associated types instead, like this:

```
trait Foo{ type T; }

struct Bar<B: Foo> {
  b: B,
}
```

otherwise (if you do need to have the type parameter on `Foo`), `PhantomData` is indeed the way to go.

You were not the only person finding `PhantomData`'s docs confusing (see [`PhantomData` is incomprehensible](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22914)). As a result, the [documentation for `PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) has been [recently improved by Steve Klabnik](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23925) and now it does mention this scenario explicitly (and not just unsafe code).

Comment: Looks like the associated type is working for me.  I did see the issue and updated docs about PhantomData and still think it's pretty weird, but at least I can avoid it for now :)

Comment: We might look into making it less weird in the future, but for now, it's a fairly low-level kind of thing, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you want is the following: for *any* type `A`, `B` must implement `Foo<A>`. That suggests that you rely on functionality of `Foo` that does not depend on the value of `A`, which means that you can change `Foo` to have an associated type rather than a type parameter.

```
trait Foo<T> { }
```

will become

```
trait Foo {
    type T;
}
```

Then you can remove the `A` type parameter everywhere and require just `B: Foo`.

To elaborate on `PhantomData`, it has nothing to do with unsafe code, it is used to determine variance of a type parameter when the compiler cannot infer it. See [RFC 738](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md) for more information on variance and `PhantomData`.