# How to use multiple levels of traits

Tags: rust, traits

I have multiple levels of traits and can't work out how to reference the types in the top level object. I get messages about parameters not used, but if I remove them I get messages about them missing! An example:

```
struct User {
  name: String,
}

trait UserStore {
  fn get_user(&self) -> User;
}

struct Tenant<U>
where
  U: UserStore,
{
  user_store: U,
}

trait TenantStore<U>
where
  U: UserStore
{
  fn get_tenant(&self) -> Tenant<U>;
}

// what to do here??
struct Application<T, U>
where
    T: TenantStore<U>,
    U: UserStore
{
  tenant_store: T,
}
```

Error:

```
parameter `U` is never used

unused parameter

help: consider removing `U`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`rustc(E0392)
```

If I remove the `U` I get:

```
cannot find type `U` in this scope
```

Comment: I bet you want an associated type instead of a type parameter. See [Struct with a generic trait which is also a generic trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094284/struct-with-a-generic-trait-which-is-also-a-generic-trait)

Comment: [That answer applied here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=246b9e6634f0184ebf0bec5f44789e77). Although I would recommend stripping off the `where` clauses from the `struct`s; they do not appear to serve any purpose.

Comment: @trentcl it looks like associated types might be what I'm after. But don't the `where` clauses on the structs have a purpose in constraining the type of the generic parameter? I don't want to have a `Tenant<i32>` for example. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Trait bounds on structs are usually only useful if the *struct definition itself* uses the trait in some way. For instance, [`std::iter::Peekable<I: Iterator>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/mod.rs.html#1425-1429) contains an `I::Item`, so removing the `I: Iterator` bound would obviously fail to compile. When the trait is not used in the struct itself, but only in `impl` blocks that define its behavior, it's less redundant to only add the bound to the `impl` blocks where it is needed...

Comment: ... as in [`std::collections::HashMap<K, V, S>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#203-205), which does not bound `K` with `Eq + Hash` or `S` with `BuildHasher` except in the `impl` blocks that define methods that use those traits. After all, if somebody hypothetically figures out a use for `Tenant<i32>`, is it really important that you stop them? Until [implied bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2089) are implemented, adding the bound on `Tenant<U>` is (IMO) just a waste of typing. The bounds on the `impl` blocks suffice.

Answer (score -1):

## Original answer

You can use [PhantomData](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) to solve the issue. Then the solution will look like
([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=897e38598e563c0b557c763008b9ce6e))

```rust
struct User {
  name: String,
}

trait UserStore {
  fn get_user(&self) -> User;
}

struct Tenant<U>
where
  U: UserStore,
{
  user_store: U,
}

trait TenantStore<U>
where
  U: UserStore
{
  fn get_tenant(&self) -> Tenant<U>;
}

// what to do here??
struct Application<T, U>
where
    T: TenantStore<U>,
    U: UserStore
{
  tenant_store: T,
  phantom_u: std::marker::PhantomData<U>
}
```

## Update#1

> It seems a bit ugly as I now have an extra parameter I need to fill in every time I create an Application, but which will never be used.

You can solve that by using [Associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html). Then the solution will looks like ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=786937bf7e47437e1130e648cd2eba9f)):

```rust
struct User {
  name: String,
}

trait UserStore {
  fn get_user(&self) -> User;
}

struct Tenant<U>
where
  U: UserStore,
{
  user_store: U,
}

trait TenantStore
{
  type U: UserStore;
  fn get_tenant(&self) -> Tenant<Self::U>;
}

struct Application<T>
where
    T: TenantStore
{
  tenant_store: T,
}
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if there will be a comment with explanation why my post have `-1`? Does it incorrect? Do we already have the question/answer for the same problem which I missed during my search for duplicates?

Comment: I saw that was one of the suggestions, but is that the only way to achieve this? It seems a bit ugly as I now have an extra parameter I need to fill in every time I create an Application, but which will never be used.

Comment: It's the only way I know. It may looks imperfect but it works.

Comment: Could you justify why you used `PhantomData<U>` and not, for instance, `PhantomData<fn() -> U>`, `PhantomData<fn(U) -> U>`, `PhantomData<fn(U)>`, `PhantomData<*mut U>`, or `PhantomData<*const U>`? Because if you're just using `PhantomData` to silence the error message, chances are pretty good you picked the wrong one.

Comment: Hi @trentcl, thanks for your question. I'm not sure I understand your question correct. I've use `PhantomData` to show the compiler that the final type of the monomorphized structure will depends on `U`. I'm not an expert in that area BTW. I believe it'll be very helpful if you can provide explanation: when each of the approaches can be used. It may be a brilliant answer for the question itself.